# Time manipulation

Tags: java, datetime

Given the assignment `t = System.currentTimeMillis(`), accrued at some point in the past, how do I get the millis of the same day as t in 12 pm and the day after 12 pm?

Comment: Which time zone? It might be 24 hours later, or 25, or 23...

Comment: I would personally use Joda Time... is that an option?

Comment: is it an external jar? if it is then i cant use it, is it impossible to acheive that in java standart packages?

Comment: No, it's not impossible - it's just uglier. It would really help if you could put all these details into the question - it's pretty unclear at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet what else do you need to know?

Comment: My point is that the original question should have stated that you couldn't use 3rd party libraries, and wanted to use the default time zone. It was also sufficiently confusing that Mohammad's answer didn't meet your needs. Basically you should edit it for clarity, and consider all of this for your next question.

Comment: Ok, though i didnt think it would metter beforehand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: this is timezone dependent. You can do as such:

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*;

final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(yourValue);
cal.set(HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
cal.set(MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(SECOND, 0);
cal.set(MILLISECOND, 0);
// cal.getTimeInMillis() contains the wanted day at 12pm
cal.add(DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
// cal.getTimeInMillis() now contains the wanted day plus one at 12pm
```

But do yourself a favour and use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), it is much easier to use in this case:

```
final DateTime dayAt12pm = new DateTime(yourValue).toDateMidnight()
    .plusHours(12);
// dayAt12pm.getMillis() contains the wanted day at 12pm
// next day at 12pm: dayAt12pm.plusDays(1).getMillis()
```

Comment: I dont need the current day, i need to get the same day as the given time t. but youre very close :)

Comment: // cal.getTimeInMillis() contains the current day at 12pm , but im looking to get the current day as t, and t could have gotten current millis a week ago...

Comment: +1 for mentioning Joda time, the standard Java date/time APIs are horrible.

Answer (score 2):

```
//plug your "T" here.
long t = System.currentTimeMillis();

Date date = new Date(t);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.setTime(date);

Calendar startOfDay = Calendar.getInstance();
startOfDay.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
startOfDay.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
startOfDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
startOfDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
startOfDay.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Date startOfDayDate = startOfDay.getTime();
System.err.println("12PM on time t is " + startOfDayDate);

startOfDay.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
startOfDayDate = startOfDay.getTime();
System.err.println("12PM day after t is " + startOfDayDate);
```

Comment: Minor quibble, the last startOfDay.add should be startOfDay.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); for leap seconds.

Comment: Adding 1 day is cleaner than adding 24 hours, but how does that address leap seconds?  My reading indicates the Java API is ignorant of leap seconds.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) from it and then use the Calendar class.